# Forcing a toggle to finish before another starts

Tags: jquery

I have four buttons that toggle a background image with a fade transition, it works fine but - when I move very quickly between them the fade is lost.

What I'd like is to force the first fade to finish before the second starts.

Is this possible?

**JS**

```
$(".first-button").hover(function(){
    $('.intro').toggleClass('intro-2')
});

$(".second-button").hover(function(){
    $('.intro').toggleClass('intro-3')        
});

$(".third-button").hover(function(){
    $('.intro').toggleClass('intro-4')        
});

$(".fourth-button").hover(function(){
    $('.intro').toggleClass('intro-5')        
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="intro">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="first-button">Caption 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="second-button">Caption 2</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#" class="third-button">Caption 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="fourth-button">Caption 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.intro {
background: url('img/image.jpg');
transition: background 300ms ease-in 0s;
}

.intro-2 {
background: url('img/image-1.jpg');
transition: background 300ms ease-in 0s;
}

.intro-3 {
background: url('img/image-2.jpg');
transition: background 300ms ease-in 0s;
}

.intro-4 {
background: url('img/image-3.jpg');
transition: background 300ms ease-in 0s;
}

.intro-5 {
background: url('img/image-4.jpg');
transition: background 300ms ease-in 0s;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) :

```
$(function() {
        $('.first-button').hover(function() {
            $('.intro').delay(300).fadeToggle();
        });
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
        $('.first-button').hover(function() {
            $('.intro').fadeToggle(300);
        });
});
```

Same for the other button or just add both class in the selector. Or add a new class which is common for both (better if total>2)

Comment: sorry, there are actually there are four buttons, I had simpified to be more succint.I don't think your solution works because I need to swap the class of the holding div from ".intro" to "intro-2, intro-3, intro-4, intro-5" etc and then back to .intro on mouseout?